# JavaScript: using THIS inside object function and binding event

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, events, this

I have an Object and I want to bind a function to a button when Object was initialized.

```
var MyClass = {
    Click: function()   {
        var a   = MyClass;    // <---------------------- look here
        a.Start();
    },
    Bind: function()    {
        var a = document.getElementById('MyButton');
        a.addEventListener('click', this.Click, false);   //<---------- and here
    },
    Init: function()    {
        this.Bind();
    }
}
```

So, I'm new at using it and I don't know if object can be declared like this (inside `Click()` function that should be done after clicking a button):

Is it a bad practise? Which could be the best way in this case when adding an event here?

**Edit:** [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prw4j3ps/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have a syntax error. `getElementsById()` should be `getElementById()` - no `s`. Once you fix that, what you have will work, however note that it's not really a class but an object.

If you did want to create this as a class to maintain scope of the contained methods and variables, and also create new instances, you can do it like this:

```js
var MyClass = function() {
  var _this = this;

  _this.click = function() {
    _this.start();
  };      

  _this.start = function() {
    console.log('Start...');
  }
  
  _this.bind = function() {
    var a = document.getElementById('MyButton');
    a.addEventListener('click', this.click, false);
  };
  
  _this.init = function() {
    _this.bind();
  };
  
  return _this;
}

new MyClass().init();
```

```html
<button id="MyButton">Click me</button>
```

Comment: It's working :) What do you mean by "also create new instances"? Does it mean that with this code I can create multiple `MyClass()` objects but with code in question that can't be done? Why?

Comment: That's right. It can't be done in your previous code because `MyClass` is an object.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For event listeners it's easiest and best to use jQuery, for example if you want to have some .js code executed when user clicks on a button, you could use: 
https://api.jquery.com/click/

I don't know how new you are to .js, but you should look up to codecademy tutorials on JavaScript and jQuery.

.click() demo:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_click

Comment: I can bind it with JQuery, but the problem is declaring object after in function Click().